# R como extrair o primeiro valor de uma lista de data.frame

Tags: r, lista, for, data.frame

Eu tenho essa lista de dados::

```
base_list <- list(structure(list(POP_84 = 17.7, POP_92 = 18.8, POP_99 = 19.7, 
                                 POP_02 = 20.5, POP_04 = 21.2, POP_09 = 23, POP_11 = 24.5), row.names = 149L, class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(POP_56 = 10.8, POP_58 = 11.5, POP_60 = 12.4, 
                                 POP_66 = 14, POP_68 = 14.3, POP_71 = 16.2, POP_84 = 18.1, 
                                 POP_92 = 21.3, POP_99 = 21, POP_02 = 21.2, POP_04 = 22, 
                                 POP_09 = 25.1), row.names = 150L, class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(POP_56 = 11.1, POP_58 = 11.1, POP_60 = 12.1), row.names = 151L, class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(POP_56 = 11.8, POP_58 = 12.1, POP_60 = 12.1, 
                                 POP_66 = 13.1, POP_68 = 14, POP_71 = 14.6, POP_84 = 13.7, 
                                 POP_92 = 15, POP_99 = 14.5, POP_02 = 14.5, POP_04 = 14.7, 
                                 POP_09 = 14.9, POP_11 = 16.1, POP_16 = 16.2), row.names = 152L, class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(POP_60 = 10.5, POP_66 = 13.1, POP_09 = 10, 
                                 POP_11 = 11.6, POP_16 = 12.6), row.names = 153L, class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(POP_09 = 10.7, POP_11 = 11.2, POP_16 = 12.8), row.names = 154L, class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(POP_56 = 12.4, POP_58 = 13.1, POP_60 = 13.1, 
                                 POP_66 = 14.3, POP_68 = 15, POP_71 = 15.6, POP_84 = 17.7, 
                                 POP_92 = 17.8, POP_99 = 18, POP_02 = 18.5, POP_04 = 18.8, 
                                 POP_09 = 19.1, POP_11 = 19.2, POP_16 = 19.9), row.names = 155L, class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(POP_99 = 12.4, POP_02 = 13.2, POP_04 = 13.8, 
                                 POP_09 = 14.7, POP_11 = 15, POP_16 = 15.2), row.names = 156L, class = "data.frame"))
```

gostaria de extrair apenas o primeiro valor de cada `data.frame` da lista.

Comment: O resultado apresentado não faz sentido. Note que `POP_56` deve ter 4 `NA`, pois aparece nas posições 2, 3, 4 e 7 de `base_list`, mas não possui nenhum `NA` no resultado pretendido. Além disso, o que significa "eu tentei pela função bind_rows(base_list) porém o resultado fica todo bagunçado"? Eu testei a função aqui e o resultado está perfeitamente organizado, inclusive colocando `NA` justamente nas linhas 1, 5, 6 e 8 do data frame final.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta. Realmente não fazia sentido algum. Consegui resolver o problema. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R é uma linguagem funcional, o operador de extração/indexação pode ser usado como uma função. Então, se `base_list[[1]][1]` extrai o primeiro valor do primeiro ítem da lista, para extrair o primeiro item de cada um dos elementos podemos usar:

```
primeiros.valores <- lapply(base_list, "[", 1)
```

Ou seja: "aplique à lista a função de extração de valor por posição com o argumento '1'". O resultado é uma lista; pode ser convertido para vetor com:

```
> unlist(primeiros.valores)
POP_84 POP_56 POP_56 POP_56 POP_60 POP_09 POP_56 POP_99 
  17.7   10.8   11.1   11.8   10.5   10.7   12.4   12.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Queria extrair o primeiro valor de cada lista.
Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

primeiro criei uma `matrix()` com o tamanho desejado:

```
pop_list <- matrix(nrow=length(df_desejado))
```

depois rodei esse loop e extrai os valores:

```
for(i in (lin)){ # loop por linha
  pop_list[i,1] <- base_list[[i]][[1]]
}
```

`lin` é o número de linhas do `df_desejado`